# Git submodules vs library dependency in scala microservice project

Tags: sbt, microservices, git-submodules

There is multi project sbt build config that contains bunch of microservices in one repo. Each microservice is self-contained. Also there is separate repository called `common` that contains shared model for the microservices.

What I would to know is how to handle dependencies between `common` project and microservices that use it.
Does git submodules approach properly fit in this case?

The one possible solution is to create submodule `common` in main repo and make each microservice dependent on that module:

```
serviceA.dependsOn(common)
serviceB.dependsOn(common) 
...
```

Another solutions is just to add specific dependency to common to every microservice:

```
serviceA
.settings(
   libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.common
)
```

What is the pros/cons each of these approaches? 
And what is the proper way to manage shared code relation in general?
Thanks is advance!